# IBM MQ ERROR "JMSCMQ0001: WebSphere MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2035' ('MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED')"

Tags: spring, eclipse, spring-boot, websphere

I have the following issue

When I launch a Spring application in Eclipse, I get the following error in the console

```
JMSCMQ0001: WebSphere MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2035' ('MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED')
```

I already entered the following command in Command Prompt to disable CHLAUTH rules

```
ALTER QMGR CHLAUTH(DISABLED)
```

But still, I can't solve the problem

¿Do you think it is due to the configuration of the local group ***mqm*** in the Computer administrator?

Answer (score 0):

What does the error log of the queue manager say? Often that log shows more information on which action or mq call was requested (connect, get, put browse,...) and by which user it was requested.

Also, disabling channel authentication doesn't disable authorization all together, it just disables the fact that channel authentication rules (address mappings, qmgr mappings, blocking rules) are applied.
The user trying to access the MQ resources still needs to have the right authorizations on those MQ resources to be able to access them.